# value input field in foreach to input field outside foreach

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, input, foreach

The problem I have is best explained with a code example:

I have the following `VIEW.jsp`:

```
<c:forEach var="widget" items="${widgets}">
        <div class="drag">
             <p>Id: ${widget.id}</p>
             <input class="editWidget" type="image" src="/tis/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit widget">
             <input class="idWidget" type="hidden" value="${widget.id}">
        </div>
</c:forEach>

<div id="editDialog" title="Edit widget">
    <fieldset>
         <input class="editWidgetId" type="hidden" value="??" id="editWidgetId">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

`editWidgetId` should have its 'value' attribute filled with the value of `idWidget` inside the `foreach` loop. This value should be different for each element in the loop (element is selected by edit button).

The questions:

1. How can I get the value of one input field to another input field?
2. How can I do this when a foreach loop is present?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want dynamic behavior, this work has to be executed on the client-side by JavaScript as at the server-side, you have **many** widgets *to* **one** editDialog and are lacking the client-side user event to make your decision.

What you want to do is assign a function handler (or statement in my example below) to each editWidget to change the value of the editWidgetId input box with the appropriate value:

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('editWidgetId').value = '${widget.id}'" class="editWidget" type="image" src="/tis/img/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit widget" >
```

Haven't tested this but I hope you get the idea

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the idea, but I hope you can help me with a little adjustment. I would like to have the document.getElement........ part in Java code, as having multiple fields would make the onclick value very complicated. In Java code '${widget.id}' becomes a string, and not a value. How does the Java version look like?

Comment: @JohnHendrik, I assumed you wanted the widget id. The code above goes in your JSP page. Your JSTL notation will go through the JSP pre-processor (Java) and for each of the output sections it'll render the onclick event. Have you tried running and looking at the source of the page?

Comment: You assumed right. I implemented the solution you suggested and it works perfect. The code is still pretty clean, so i'm happy with it. Thank you very much:)